# NodeJS/Gulp SyntaxError position in JSON

Tags: json, node.js, gulp-watch

So I'm using the `gulp watch` command over a certain directory containing lots of JSON files and it gives out the following stacktrace :

```
[18:02:54] Plumber found unhandled error:
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 4
[18:02:54] Plumber found unhandled error:
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 9
[18:02:54] Plumber found unhandled error:
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 5207
[18:02:54] Plumber found unhandled error:
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 873
[18:02:54] Plumber found unhandled error:
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 5283
```

What do these positions mean, how can I narrow down which files have these syntax errors?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used gulp-plumber, but I've done some investigating to try and help.  [According to the comments on this article](https://cameronspear.com/blog/how-to-handle-gulp-watch-errors-with-plumber/), if you put `console.log(err.toString());` in your plumber's error handling callback, before the `this.emit('end')`, you will get a printout of the relevant information for the error.  If that doesn't give you the file name and specific error location, you could try `console.log(err)` will is supposed to print out the full stack trace.